# turn flask html report into csv

Tags: python, csv, email, flask, sqlalchemy

I am creating a Flask app that creates a table from the user input, then allows the user to run a report through the columns.  The user should select a column from the database and retrieve the data; after this the user can enter the email so to send the report to.

The report function works but it doesn't do anything when the email entry has been filled.  To test this I has just attempted to display the column in a single comma separated string value.

This doesn't work and brings back:
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.

This doesn't work and brings back:

```
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

sendreport.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect, flash, session
from flask_mail import Mail, Message

app = Flask(__name__)

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, select
meta = MetaData()
engine = create_engine("postgresql://username:password@localhost/test-db-02", echo = True)
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

class TestValue(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test_value'
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    val1 = Column('val1', String(15))
    val2 = Column('val2', String(15))
    val3 = Column('val3', String(15))
    val4 = Column('val4', String(15))
    val5 = Column('val5', String(15))

    def __init__(self, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5):
        self.val1 = val1
        self.val2 = val2
        self.val3 = val3
        self.val4 = val4
        self.val5 = val5

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
db_session = Session()

@app.route('/tablelog', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def tablelog():
    title = "Log Table"
    category = request.form.get("val_category")
    item1 = request.form.get("val_item1")
    item2 = request.form.get("val_item2")
    item3 = request.form.get("val_item3")
    item4 = request.form.get("val_item4")
    if request.method == 'GET':
        data = db_session.query(TestValue).all()
        return render_template('tablelog.html', title=title, data=data)
    else:
        db_entry = TestValue(category, item1, item2, item3, item4)
        db_session.add(db_entry)
        db_session.commit()
        data = db_session.query(TestValue).all()
        return render_template('tablelog.html', title=title, data=data)

@app.route('/reports', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def reports():
    title = "SPA Reports"
    rv = request.form.get("report_val")
    sendEmail = request.form.get("sendEmail")
    sub_report = request.form.get("sub-btn")
    val_data = db_session.query(TestValue).order_by(TestValue.id)
    data = val_data.all()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('reports.html', title=title, data=data)
    elif rv == "val1" and sendEmail != None:
        category = val_data.all()
        if sub_report:
            for d in category.id:
                csv = str(f'{d}, ')
                return f"{csv}"
        return render_template('reports.html', title=title, category=category)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

snippet of reports.html :

```
{% if category %}
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>CATEGORIES</th>
    </tr>
    {% for f in category %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ f.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ f.val1 }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endif %}
<br><br>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="sendEmail" placeholder="Enter email here">
    <button type="submit" name="sub" value="sub-btn">SEND EMAIL!</button>
</div>
```

---

In regards to the csv part, what I want to achieve is something like:

```
data = ["hello", "world", "from", "sinclair"]
for d in data:
    d1 = data[0]
    d2 = data[1]
    d3 = data[2]
    d4 = data[3]
    csv = str(f'{d1}, {d2}, {d3}, {d4}')
    print(csv)
```

This should print:

```
hello world from sinclair
```

Comment: When posting a debugging question, please include the traceback, not just the error message. In `reports()` the statement `return f"{csv}"` in the for-loop looks a bit fishy. On the subject of "fishy" expressions, `str(f'{d}, ')` seems a bit redundant. A format-string is a string.

Comment: oh ok sorry, its says something about # the body must not be none and references if rv is None then raises a TypeError.  it then states # make sure the body is an instance of the response class